# Gnome-Do in doesn't have the docky appearance anymore

Tags: 10.10, gnome-do, docky

I know docky can be installed seperately from gnome-do but I like both and don't want to install both app when I can install one only. Is there a way to get docky back in gnome-do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Docky and Do were split after it became clear that the Docky theme for Do was collecting a huge amount of code not shared with anything else in Do.

The Docky found in the `docky` package has a large number of extra features and a huge number of bugs fixed (particularly with respect to window matching) compared to the docky theme from Do.

You will have a better dock experience with the stand-alone `docky` package than with the docky theme of the (previous) `gnome-do` package.

Answer (score 4):

Docky and Gnome-Do are now two separate programs. If you want to install Docky, just go to the software center and search for "Docky" and it will come right up.

You would have to use an old and out-of-date version of Gnome Do to have them both integrated into the same application. It's actually much better that there are now two programs. You get better features and a more stable framework since Docky and GnomeDo were starting to grow into two separate entities.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the themes for Gnome Do? Last time I used it on Lucid Lynx, on the list of themes for Gnome Do there was the dock theme available.

Docky has moved forward from Gnome Do to become a dock application only. But, as I recall the dock option is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that when you activate gnome-do, it pops up where docky would normally be?

From what I understand, you're going to need to have both apps installed. Don't worry, you can have docky disabled but still achieve the cool gnome-do affect.

If you need help with that let me know, and i'll edit my post with the info.

P.S. I reread your question and wanted to say that they are independent applications, but are made by the same company and are designed to be somewhat intertwined (AKA you get more functionality by running both at the same time.)

Answer (score 0):

Docky Split from gnome-do a long time ago, it looks as if the transition is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Now there are two seperate applications docky and gnome-do, but according to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/446049), there might be a gnome-do integration in docky in future. At least by now the milestone is set to Docky 3.0.0 (but earlier it was 2.2.0 but then moved to 3.0.0 when 2.2.0 was published). So we'll see.