# Does Gnome-Do (with the Docky theme) work well with 10.10 Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, compatibility, gnome-do

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnome-Do in doesn't have the docky appearance anymore.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5790/gnome-do-in-doesnt-have-the-docky-appearance-anymore)

Since development of Gnome-Do has halted while the world continues to spin, I was wondering if there are any compatibility issues with the Docky theme of Gnome-Do (as opposed to Docky "proper") in Maverick?

I much prefer Do to Docky, and would rather continue using it.

Answer (score 1):

[Gnome-Do in Maverick doesn't have the docky appearance anymore.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5790/gnome-do-in-doesnt-have-the-docky-appearance-anymore)